# How works SQL Injection with html form?

Tags: mysql, sql

someone sql inject my Project and filled a  on my site.
How it works? 
I mean, i found the break where he comes in.

I have this, in one file. And i forgot to save it.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE info SET `value`='".$_POST["chat"]."' WHERE `name`='chatactive'");
```

The "chat" Post can easy set in a input field. And the Value is variable.
But the guy who breaks into my site changes the

But the guy changes the value of WHERE name = infotitle
and not chatactive

How he do this?
The only value he can changed was the "POST chat". But he dont changed anything there, only in name = "infotitle"

I tried things like

`"1', value='<script> WHERE name='infotitle'`

as value. But it dont work cause mysql says error cause there is

`"WHERE name='chatactive'");"`

behind the POST value

Answer (score 1):

A quote is the key part to make a SQL injection

He typed this in the chat:

> anything' WHERE name='chatactive';

Your query becomes

```
UPDATE info SET `value`='anything' WHERE name='chatactive';' WHERE `name`='infotitle'
```

MySQL first executes

```
UPDATE info SET `value`='anything' WHERE name='infotitle';
```

Then tries to execute:

```
WHERE `name`='chatactive
```

The first query succeed. The second fails, but it doesn't matter as the goal is achieved.

I guess he was a very gentle aka ethical hacker.

Comment: I tried like that 

`UPDATE info SET `value`='NOTICE 1' WHERE `name`='infotitle'; UPDATE info SET `value`='1' WHERE `name`='chatactive'`

It works in SQL with phpmyadmin

but not when i give it to Post input value

---- Your code "anything' WHERE name='infotitle';" dont work too. Only in PHPmyadmin SQL, but not in html form value post

Comment: Debug to see where the difference is :  `$sql='the query'; echo $sql; mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: i think it the apostrophe's -> ' <-

Comment: Read 5 times the very first line of my answer. Then check what goes right after "anything". quote=apostrophe

Comment: yes i know it. But when i type `anything' WHERE name='infotitle';` it dont work, cause the update dont work with php to mysql. SQL in phpmyadmin with it works. I tried with `\'` but than sql writes all name="chat" --- Than i have this in sql value `NOTICE 1' WHERE `name`='infotitle'; UPDATE info SET `value`='1` --- I cannot write Quotes in form field value i mean...

Comment: I tried like you sayed... but dont work... hm. Only works in SQL with phpmyadmin, but not as value in form, cause i mean he dont see or accept the quotes with commit the form

Comment: It's unclear to me why your POST value doesn't accept quotes. Do you have a client side javascript preventing this ? There are other means to pass a quote into the SQL : use of hex value `0x27` for instance, or in case of a GET : html entity  `&quot;` .  Search for this. The quote is the key. He obviously managed to pass it

Comment: I dont know why... hm. I dont have client side blocking this... with $quot; he write this in the value... but not executing it... Thats why i asked here. I know that the quote must this, but it dont works... do you mean he can post a form with url? or inspect site console in chrome or anything?

Comment: I also tried this in console: `$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.php',
                data : {
                    chatpost: '2',
                    chat: 'anything&#39; WHERE name=&#39;infotitle&#39;;'
                }
            }); `

But than i have this inserted as string in my chat value

Comment: I tried something! Here is an error log and the $sql that he will query...
`UPDATE info SET `value`='NOTICE 1' WHERE `name`='infotitle'; UPDATE info SET `value`='1' WHERE `name`='chatactive'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE info SET `value`='1' WHERE `name`='chatactive'' at line 1` this is what i typed in: NOTICE 1' WHERE `name`='infotitle'; UPDATE info SET `value`='1. You have skype? its better to write faster and see better

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, then you *must* move away from the `mysql_*` interface.  Go to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Then you *must* escape or "bind" all arguments before building SQL.  In particular, `$_POST[]`, `$_GET[]`, and `$_REQUEST[]` are the doors through which hackers try to get into your database.

Once in, an evil hacker can literally destroy all the data on your disk.